# serializing single elements of CXML-STP:DOCUMENT

Tags: common-lisp

I got the following XML

```
<EXAMPLE>   
  <WANNAPRINT>    
   AWESOME  
  </WANNAPRINT>   
  <DONTWANNAPRINT>
   BAD   
  </DONTWANNAPRINT> 
</EXAMPLE>
```

I work with the given XML using [CXML-STP](http://www.lichteblau.com/cxml-stp/) and I only want to print the "wannaprint" section.

I am trying to achieve this using serialize:

```
(cxml-stp:serialize 
 (let ((last-step 
    (car 
     (cxml-stp:filter-children #'(lambda(node)
                       (and (typep node 'stp:element)
                        (string= (stp:local-name node)
                             "WANNAPRINT")))
                   (cxml-stp:first-child 
                    (cxml:parse 
                     "<EXAMPLE>
  <WANNAPRINT>
   AWESOME
  </WANNAPRINT>
  <DONTWANNAPRINT>
  BAD
  </DONTWANNAPRINT>
 </EXAMPLE>" (stp:make-builder)))))))
   (FORMAT t "last-step:~a~%" last-step)
   last-step)
 (cxml:make-string-sink))
```

But the result is simply "nil" and I do not understand why, as the printing of the "last-step" variable shows that the correct element has been selected.

**How can I serialize/print an element of the cxml-stp:document into a string?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for `cxml:make-string-sink`, the string sinks return their strings as a result of a call to `sax:end-document`, so one thing you could do would be:

```
(let ((sink (cxml:make-string-sink)))
  (cxml-stp:serialize 
   (let ((last-step 
          (car 
           (cxml-stp:filter-children #'(lambda(node)
                                         (and (typep node 'stp:element)
                                              (string= (stp:local-name node)
                                                       "WANNAPRINT")))
                                     (cxml-stp:first-child 
                                      (cxml:parse 
                                       "<EXAMPLE> <WANNAPRINT> AWESOME </WANNAPRINT> <DONTWANNAPRINT> BAD </DONTWANNAPRINT> </EXAMPLE>"
                                       (stp:make-builder)))))))
     (FORMAT t "last-step:~a~%" last-step)
     last-step)
   sink)
  (sax:end-document sink))
```

This seems a little icky, but there doesn't seem to be a mechanism exported to get at the ystream inside the sink.

Another way to do it would be to put your `element` (that is, `last-step`) in a `document`.  I thought it would be as simple as `(stp:make-document last-step)` but it complains that the element already has a parent and I don't remember how to get around that right now.  In any case, you might not want a document because its serialization includes the prelude (`<?xml`...`?>`).